# Map cpanel Add On domains to subsites in Wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, dns, cpanel, multisite, domain-mapping

I have a server where I have several domains set up as "Add On" domains on cPanel. Those domains are fully hosted, as I have emails set ups and a folder with a Wordpress installation for each one. All domains nameservers are the same, (as they runs on the same sever).

As the Wordpress sites of each domains are quite basic I am trying to set them in a multisite installation (with subfolders).

But I can't find how to map each domain to respective subsite folder.
I am experienced to map domains to multisites installations from another servers and in the same server with parked domains, but in this case is different as the domains resolves to their own folder instead of the Wordpress subsite.
Has anybody faced a similar scenario and can help me with this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's be clear that if you want to use custom domains in your WP multisite network then you don't need separate wordpress folder/installations for each site.

All your addon domains should point to your main WP multsite folder. For example if example.com is your main domain of WP Multisite network and it points to "public_html" folder then your addon domains say domain2.com should also point to the same folder which is "public_html"

Comment: Thank you @Ehsan!!, I have edited each subsite domain "Document Root" in cPanel (under Domains / Add On Domains) with the main installation folder.
Then I set each subsite Site Address (URL) with that domain. Now it works!